# disable select for certain input

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, html-select

I want to disable a select attribute when my type = radio input is checked.
Here's the part of the code i'm talking about:

```
<input id="societeInterne" name="radioSociete" type="radio" value="Interne"/><label>Interne / </label>
<input id="societeExterne" name="radioSociete" type="radio" value="Externe"/><label>Externe - </label>
<label for="PrestataireStit"> Préciser le STIT </label>
   <ol>
    <li style="list-style-type: disc">
       <select id="selectPresta">
        <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
            <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
        <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
       </select>
    </li>
   </ol>
```

What I want is that when the input "societeExterne" isn't selected, the select "selectPresta" be disabled. I tried with different types of function in javascript but none of them worked:

```
var radioExterne = document.getElementById('societeExterne');
var radioInterne = document.getElementById('societeInterne');
var selectPresta = document.getElementById('selectPresta');


if (radioExterne.checked) {
    selectPresta.disabled = false;
} else {
    selectPresta.disabled = true;
}
```

---

```
var radioExterne = document.getElementById('societeExterne');
var radioInterne = document.getElementById('societeInterne');
var selectPresta = document.getElementById('selectPresta');

radioExterne.addEventListener(
  "change",
  (event) => {
    selectPresta.disabled = !event.target.checked;
  },
  false,
);
```

Comment: Radios can only be unchecked when another in the group is clicked, so `event.target.checked` will always be true, thus `selectPresta.disabled` will always be false.

Comment: Also, radio buttons cannot be unchecked; one always has to be checked. Maybe you need checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you wrap your content in a `form` element, then you can listen for a change of the form and toggle `selectPresta.disabled` accordingly:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var radioExterne = document.getElementById('societeExterne');
var selectPresta = document.getElementById('selectPresta');
//listen for a change in the form
form.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    //does the value of form.radioSociete not match that of radioExterne?
    selectPresta.disabled = !(form.radioSociete.value == radioExterne.value);
});
//trigger change on load to set initial state
form.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <label><input id="societeInterne" name="radioSociete" type="radio" value="Interne" />Interne / </label>
  <label><input id="societeExterne" name="radioSociete" type="radio" value="Externe" />Externe - </label>
  <label for="PrestataireStit"> Préciser le STIT </label>
  <ol>
    <li style="list-style-type: disc">
      <select id="selectPresta">
        <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
        <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
        <option value='GROUPE presta' name='Societe presta'>presta</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: hey man thanks a lot even though it wasn't doing exactly what i wanted it helped me find the solution so thank you very much you're my savior!

Comment: @GoldaKen You're welcome. I had misread your requirements. I have corrected my example to disable selectPresta unless societeExterne is selected. Please upvote and/or accept my answer if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

#### Add this to your script tag

```
    //set element to be disabled by default
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('selectPresta');

    function enableSelectElement() {
        var selectedRadio = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').id;
        //set element to be enabled/disabled by calling function
        selectElement.disabled = selectedRadio !== 'societeExterne';
    };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).